# Safe Keeping Oauth Tokens in a Cookie?

Tags: node.js, cookies, oauth, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have been keeping my 3 legged auth tokens and the refresh token in cookies so then I can transfer them after reload. I am on localhost so I didn't have to think about security but soon enough I will be putting my web application on the internet. I know that you should only have a token with viewables:read as the only scope to prevent any snooping of the user's data. Can it be safe if I encrypt the token with my own encryption method or should I keep the token in a mySQL session on the server side? If I should make mySQL session, can someone give me a link to a tutorial on the mySQL session parser npm extension? I haven't got it to work in the past. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 3-legged token that will give access only to that user data. If that token is `viewables:read` the user will be able to view his/her models, nothing else. You can use proxy on Viewer to avoid sending it to the client, [see a NodeJS sample](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy).

The refresh token is useless to that user, to actually refresh it the ID & secret are required (and the secret should be hidden, the ID can be exposed for BIM 360 provisioning, for instance).

Assuming the browser is not compromised and your cookie is configured to use only `https`, then the cookie is only exposed to the website that created it and protected during transfer.

I use [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) on my sample apps, [like this](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage).